# Is it possible to rename multiple directories with a command line in windows?

Tags: windows, command, rename

I would like to be able to rename multiple directories names's selected parts with a command line in windows.

I looked for the "ren" command, which works with files. For example you can do ren miss*.txt mister*.txt, and all of the files containing miss in their name will have the "miss" modify to "mister", without modify the rest of the file's name. But it is not working with directories names (command line doesn't recognize the "*" command), and I would like to know if someone know a command line which can do the same with directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If powershell is an option, you can use following one-liner

```
gci -di miss* | ren -n {$_.fullname -replace 'miss', 'mister'}
```

In full

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory miss* | 
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.fullname -replace 'miss', 'mister'}
```

Comment: It is not working, it says me "'Get-ChildItem' is not recognize as intern command". But thanks for the try

Comment: @Anacarde - you have to open a powershell prompt io a plain cmd window. Or just type powershell in your cmd window and execute the one-liner

Comment: Woh, it worked, thanks a lot ! I did not know that command. I'm gonna to study that. Thanks

Comment: @Anacarde - you are welcome. I didn't know rename could be used with wildcards so you can call it even.

Comment: Hello Lieven, I went to the powershell doc, and I found nowhere the alias "-n" for "-NewName". It shows alias of commands (with "Get-Alias"), but not for parameters. How did you got those informations ?

Comment: `-n` is not an alias, it's a parameter. You can shorten parameters as long as they remain unambiguous. The `Rename-Item` command has only one parameter starting with `-n` so that's all you have to type. You can try with the letter `p`which is not unambiguous. There's an `path` and a `passthru` parameter so `ren -p` or `ren -pa` will fail with `Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'pa' is ambiguous`.

Comment: Thank you :) but still, I wonder how do you know that we can enter -n for NewName. (I did research for couple of hours -_-, and I saw that nowhere, do you have a link for a doc about shorten parameters.. ?)

Comment: Ah... I guess I understood. As long as you have the parameters list, you know that you can enter just the first letter, except if there are several parameters beginning with that letter. Is it something like that ?

Comment: @Anacarde - yes, it's exactly like that. Rereading my comment, I explained it badly but you got it anyway ;)